# Perform soft reset without losing RAM Data on ARM cortex M4

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I am working on controller having architecture of ARM CORTEX M4. 
Flash of controller contains 2 different applications Boot loader and Application.
I want allocated RAM section via to store some data which I will share in both boot loader and application.
Problem for me is when I jump from one application to another(Reset vector) my RAM section data from which I want to persist is getting cleared.
As I am new to this kind of implementation, please guide me how can I achieve such implementation where RAM data will persist after soft reset or jump from one application to another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correction : I have allocated RAM section via scatter file to store some data which I will share in both boot loader and application

Comment: take over or replace the bootstrap so that it doesnt initialize memory.  Note that cortex-m4 is too vague, what chip are you using (cortex-m4 is not a chip).  the chip vendor may do an sram init that you cannot get around.

Comment: I am using XMC4400 controller

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Answer (score 3):

This will be linker dependant, so look at the manual for your linker to see how to make a memory region not be initialised.

Depending on your microcontroller too, there may be some memory you can use, in the RTC peripheral of STM32s for instance there are some (20 x 32bit) back up registers which wouldn't be initialised and persist in low power states.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. is there any way to tell compiler/linker that do not initialise RAM section I have allocated on reset or jump to reset vector?

Comment: Yes, but you need to look at the manual for your linker to find out what it is :)